# How can I turn-off my laptop screen immediately if I want to?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, linux-mint, screensaver

How can I turn-off my laptop screen immediately if I want to?

Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad

(Dual Boot)
OS1: Linux Mint 17
OS2: Windows 8

I know there is power management, but it is not immediately. Need to set a time, and for Linux, the shortest is 5 minutes.

Is there any add-ons/extensions or software that can be downloaded so if I press a key, the screen will be turned off immediately?

Comment: Have you tried changing the video output to external?

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `xset dpms force off` will turn off your screen immediately on linux. You might be able to set a macro for it

I use [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and the command `nircmd monitor off` on windows.

Pair this up with your favourite macro software such as [xbindkeys on linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys) or autohotkey on windows.

Comment: Where to type "xset dpms force off", in Terminal of Linux? Then how to turn back ON?

Comment: In terminal/cmd.exe for both. Hitting any key turns it back on.

Comment: I have tried it just now, it works, thanks. Is the screen "blank" that way or really "Turned-OFF", which one? I will also try it in windows, will look for NIRCMD to download.

Comment: Its turned off. An external monitor will be on standby mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [hot corner](https://superuser.com/questions/522187/how-do-i-set-a-hot-corner-in-windows-7) where if you go to a corner of the monitor, the screen saver is activated. I remember this used to be an old Mac OS feature with screen savers like AfterDark. They have tools similar for Windows.