# Windows 8.1 randomly went to lock screen - is it possible the sysadmin caused this?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, administrator, remote-access

I was using my work PC normally and it suddenly went to the lock screen.  I did not touch the keyboard and I was using the mouse, merely reading my e-mail in Google Chrome.

Is it possible for the system administrator to view a user's PC screen on the network and even control the PC without the user's authorization, knowledge or confirmation (via a dialogue or something)?  Is this possible with standard Microsoft out-of-the-box network admin software?

Is there anything I should look for in my Task Manager that might indicate this is the case?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/522187/how-do-i-set-a-hot-corner-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Sure, an admin can take remote control of your computer user Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe). Third party software can do this too, but you asked Microsoft solution.

When an admin takes remote control using mstsc.exe his Windows session will be started and yours will go to locked state.

You can see this in the Event Viewer in "Applications and Services Logs -> Windows -> TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager" if you are an administrator of your computer.

And admin can also remote lock your pc using PsExec without taking over your pc:

```
psexec \\REMOTEPCNAME -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD "rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation"
```

But this a lot less likely than an admin taking over your pc with a remote desktop connection.

Comment: Thanks. Please let me know if this is logged then once you've tested. :)